# Show route between two location using googlemap in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I have to show route between two locations using google map, but i am getting just straight line between two location, I am using below code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20
                                                                 zoom:6];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
    marker.title = @"Sydney";
    marker.snippet = @"Australia";
    marker.map = mapView_;



    GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
    [path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(@(-33.860).doubleValue,@(151.208).doubleValue)];
    [path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(@(-32.860).doubleValue,@(150.208).doubleValue)];

    GMSPolyline *rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
    rectangle.strokeWidth = 2.f;
    rectangle.map = mapView_;

    self.view = mapView_;

}
```

Please tell me how to do this, i have seen various previous this type question but not getting.
Please help me... 
Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work this way. You are adding only two coordinates to your `GMSMutablePath`, so the resulting `GMSPolyline` is a straight line.

If you want to get routes between two points you will need to use a directions API such as [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) that calculates directions between locations using an HTTP request.

Comment: https://github.com/ManoMarks/demos/tree/master/DirectionsAPIAsync/MapsDirections i have tried this way but still not getting any direction